# Vector analysis in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus, coordinate-transformation, differential-geometry

It is known that vector calculus in 3D takes quite a simple form when one uses orthonormal curvilinear coordinates (check out, for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates#Vector_and_tensor_calculus_in_three-dimensional_curvilinear_coordinates), in section "Differentiation"). Is there any possibility to easily use this approach in Mathematica currently (giving just metric tensor $g$ and using some kind of "Laplacian($f$, $g$)" and "Gradient($f$, $g$)", for instance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are satisfied with the metrics defined in `CoordinateChartData[]`:

```
CoordinateChartData[] //Short
```

> {{{Bipolar,{\[FormalA]}},Euclidean,2},{{BipolarCylindrical,{\[FormalA]}},Euclidean,3},<<62>>,{Stereographic,{Sphere,{\[FormalCapitalR]}},10}}

then you can do things like:

```
Grad[f[r, θ, z], {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{f^{(1,0,0)}(r,\theta ,z),\frac{f^{(0,1,0)}(r,\theta ,z)}{r},f^{(0,0,1)}(r,\theta ,z)\right\}$

and:

```
Laplacian[g[r, θ, ϕ], {r, θ, ϕ}, "Spherical"] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\frac{g^{(0,2,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r}+g^{(1,0,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r}+g^{(2,0,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )+\frac{\csc (\theta ) \left(\sin
>    (\theta ) g^{(1,0,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )+\frac{\cos (\theta ) g^{(0,1,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r}+\frac{\csc (\theta ) g^{(0,0,2)}(r,\theta ,\phi
>    )}{r}\right)}{r}$